# Is it possible to use REST Api on a dedicated device offline?

Tags: here-api

We create a device (no iOS or Android) on which we would like to display offline maps (by cache country or city) Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Premium SDK, that you can download from developer.here.com, for iOS or Android.

Comment: But my hardware doesn't support iOS or Android, is a custom one.